# @Input @Output and EventEmitter in Angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm building an app with Angular 4 & Ionic 3 and I'm struggling with components:

I made a component `MesuresPreventionsComponent` (excuse my french :p) , this component needs a list from his parent component (the Ionic Page), but I'd also like it to be able to update the list in the parent component.

So I learned about @Input and @Output and thought I would use an EventEmitter to detect changes and update the list from the parent.

I've read this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37855138/2993111) and figured out how to do it.

So this is what i did :

```js
@Output() targetChange: EventEmitter<Array<any>> = new EventEmitter<Array<any>>();

@Input() set target(value){
    this.target = value;
  };
```

Then I emit my data on button click this way:

```js
alert.addButton({
    text: 'Ok',
    handler: (data: any) => {
      this.targetChange.emit(data);
      console.log('Radio data:', data)
    }
})
```

On my parent component (the ionic page) I'm using my `MesuresPreventionsComponent` in template :

```
<mesures-preventions  [(target)]="conditionsGeneralesDeTravail.mesuresPreventionsConseillees" ></mesures-preventions>
```

But the thing is the `@Input() set target(value)` is called over 9000 times when the page loads, throwing a Range Error :

> Uncaught (in promise): RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>   RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at MesuresPreventionsComponent.set [as target] (http://localhost:8100/build/0.js:153:23)
>       at MesuresPreventionsComponent.set [as target] (http://localhost:8100/build/0.js:154:25)
>       at MesuresPreventionsComponent.set [as target] (http://localhost:8100/build/0.js:154:25)
>       at MesuresPreventionsComponent.set [as target] (http://localhost:8100/build/0.js:154:25)
>       at MesuresPreventionsComponent.set [as target] (http://localhost:8100/build/0.js:154:25)
>       at MesuresPreventionsComponent.set [as target] (http://localhost:8100/build/0.js:154:25)
>       at MesuresPreventionsComponent.set [as target] (http://localhost:8100/build/0.js:154:25)
>       at MesuresPreventionsComponent.set [as target] (http://localhost:8100/build/0.js:154:25)
>       at MesuresPreventionsComponent.set [as target] (http://localhost:8100/build/0.js:154:25)
>       at MesuresPreventionsComponent.set [as target] (http://localhost:8100/build/0.js:154:25)

I tried to make a `console.log` in the `set target(value)` method and it's displayed indeed 2k times in a second.

I have no idea why this method is executing itself in loop.

Could anyone help ?

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling target inside target setter.

Replace :

```
@Input() set target(value) {
  this.target = value;
};
```

By :

```
@Input() target;
```

Also, you can't use bidirectional binding `[(target)]` you should replace it by `[target]`. If you want to create components with bidirectional binding, take a look at [this alligator.io tutorial](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/).