# Custom Component in Angular with ngModel and multiple fields

Tags: javascript, angular

So lets say I want a create a custom component in Angular 2+ for the following class

```
public class user {
    name: string;
    id: number;
    address: string;
}
```

I've created a custom component

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name" />
<input [(ngModel)]="id" />
<input [(ngModel)]="address" />
```

I've added this custom component into my main page

```
<user-component></user-component>
```

What I want to do now is pass the User class as ngModel inside my custom component and bind it with `public user:User` variable in my main page class. Something like this

```
<user-component [(ngModel)]="user"></user-component>
```

I've found few examples of using `ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` but all these examples work with single component like one text input. Is there a way to make it work for multiple inputs inside the custom component as well?

Comment: you should use reactive forms

Answer (score 7):

The way to achieve this is to use @Input on the UserComponent

```
export class UserComponent {
  @Input() user: User;
}
```

Then binding to the input you declared in your parent template

```
<user-component [user]="user"></user-component>
```

Now this is only one way, input **to** the UserComponent,

To make it two ways like ngModel works you would need to add the output EventEmiter
As follows

```
export class UserComponent {
  @Input() user: User;
  @Output('userChange') emitter: EventEmitter<User> = new EventEmitter<User>();
}
```

Note that the user**Change** keyword is important here to make it work.

Only then you would be able to write the two way binding

```
<user-component [(user)]="user"></user-component>
```

---

Adding a bit of reading docs here [angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-property](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-property)

Also with just a google search away, i was able to find this also good SO answer on the same topic [custom-input-and-output-on-same-name-in-angular2-2-way-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37855050/custom-input-and-output-on-same-name-in-angular2-2-way-binding)

Comment: As everyone is pointing out, a nice life saver would be to use https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#grouping-form-controls
a FormGroup with FormControls inside

Comment: If I use reactive forms, will I get two way data binding ?

Comment: Reactive forms help to manage values and validity of the inputs.

For example you can subscribe to a FormControls change events.
You still need the input outputs on the component to notify the parent component.

Comment: @Simplicity's_Strength, is an object, it's NOT necesary `@Output`, see e.g. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jvvmjg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Eliseo good point, this two way binding example is not needed in case you can bind to the Object directy. Your answer and stackblitz are valids for OPs initial need.

Answer (score 1):

as you has **an object** you can simple pass the object as `@Input` and

```
<user-component [user]="user"></user-component>
```

And your child

```
@Input() user:any

<input [(ngModel)]="user.name" />
<input [(ngModel)]="user.id" />
<input [(ngModel)]="user.address" />
```

NOTE: Really I love ReactiveForms, cheer up to use these

Comment: Yes I can pass the object, but once user updates the input fields inside custom component, will I get updated filed values in main component ?